# How do I go about rot/mold under bathroom sink?

Tags: sink, mold, replacement, vanity, rot

I just found a leak from the hot water line under the bathroom sink and there was tons of water. It's all dry and cleaned up now, and I shut the water line off already so there is no more water leaking. I tore out the tiling that was underneath (previous owner used tiling in the cabinet under the sink), which was adhered to linoleum. There is mold on the linoleum and on the lower walls inside the cabinet, and the bottom of the cabinet is even pitted from being weighed down by a wet tissue box. Even if I replace the rotten cabinet flooring, would the mold on the sides be a problem even if I clean it up? Would I be better off getting a new vanity for the bathroom sink?

Comment: spray it with some bleach and observe